# Deleting Java project and then creating the same one in the same directory - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having difficulties creating a Java project in Eclipse on the same location where the deleted project was. What happens when I change the new project location to the one where the old project was is all my options become grayed out. I cannot select the JRE or change the project layout. I cannot pick whether I want to create `module-info.java` file or not. It seems like Eclipse somehow knows there was a project on the same location. If that is the case, how can I delete Eclipse Project creation history?

*New Java Project* dialog info message:

```
The wizard will automatically configure the JRE and the project layout based on the existing source.
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you check _Delete project contents on disk (cannot be undone)_ or did you delete the project directory outside of Eclipse?

Comment: I deleted the project through eclipse and checked the option to delete contents on disk.

Comment: Can you create a `*.txt` file in the project folder?

Comment: Yes, I can create the new project successfully and then add a .txt file to it, but what bothers me is that I can't change the options while creating the project.

Comment: Could you please show a screenshot where you can't change the options?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the question.

Comment: The dialog says `The wizard will automatically configure the JRE and the project layout based on the existing source.` which means Eclipse found in the given directory at least the hidden `.project` file.

Comment: How can I delete that .project file?

Comment: Close Eclipse and delete the folder `Test` that seems still containing the `.project` file.

Comment: The problem is, folder Test doesn't exist. The previous project was in that folder, but was deleted in Eclipse and also disk contents were deleted. I've also checked if it is maybe hidden, but it isn't.

Comment: Strange. Please double-check via command line `cd "C:\Users\***\Desktop\***\Test"` if you get `The system cannot find the path specified.`.

Comment: A strange thing happened. When I ran that command in Cmd, I indeed got The system cannot find the path specified.  But, when I opened Eclipse after that and tried to create new project on the same directory, I got all options available. Thank you very much! I still have one more question: Why can't I create module-info.java if my Project Layout is set to use project folder as root for sources and class files? When I set it to create separate folders for sources and class files, I then get the option to create module-info.java

Comment: After project creation, does right-clicking the project and choosing _Configure > Create module-info.java_ work? Or is the menu item also disabled? Do you use some synchronization software which might explain the recreation of already deleted files?

Comment: When I right-click the project after creation and chose _Configure > Create module-info.java_, I get an error: _No source folder exists in the project._ I guess Eclipse is expecting a src folder in the project, but I don't see why that is. I don't use a synchronization software.

Comment: I was not aware, the project folder can be used as source folder. But indeed, in this case, I get the same error message. Please report it to Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a project in Eclipse, you get a dialog like this:

[image]

As you can see, the default is that the project **content** is not delete, only the project *registration* in Eclipse.

Since the actual project files are left on disk, you can "import" the project back into Eclipse, using `File` > `Import...`.

When you try to create a new project, but select a folder on disk that already contains a project, the "Create Project" dialog automatically becomes an "Import Project" dialog.

If you don't want to import that project, either select another folder, or delete the folder first.

Next time you delete a project, check the `Delete` checkbox, so all the project files and source files are deleted too.

Comment: I actually did delete project contents on disk as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have deleted all the hidden files in the directory.

Comment: Yes, I've changed File Explorer Options to show all hidden files and system protected files. There are no such files in the directory I'm creating the project in.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's deleted on your machine in your file explorer. If it's not deleted correctly it can still be save on your machine.